# Ascending number sorting - sort()

Tags: javascript

The call to `n.sort(sortNo)` doesn't specify any parameters for the function `sortNo` (which defines parameters of `a` and `b`). Can anyone explain why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function sortNo(a,b)
 {
    return a - b;
 }
 var n = ["10", "5", "40", "25", "100", "1"];
 document.write(n.sort(sortNo));
</script>
```

Is `return a - b;` the formulae used?

I know that `sortNo` is provided with two items. Does a numerical operation return the following?

- a negative value, if `a` is before `b`
- a positive value, if `b` is before `a`
- zero: if `a` and `b` are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both a and b are strings. So a-b makes no sense.

Use

```
     function sortNumber(a,b)
     {
        if (a < b)
           return 1;
       else if(a>b)
           return -1;
       return 0;
     }
```

Comment: Ok..thanks..                                                          But, Why sortNo in n.sort(sortNo) doesn't specify any parameter of a and b?

Comment: The function n.sort user your function sortNo to determine the order. You are just passing a reference to the function. The function sort will call your function sortNo whenever it wants to compare two objects of the array and depending on the return value will take the decision on how to sort.

Comment: Ok..so whenever you are passing a reference to the function..i.e. function within function then there is no need to pass the parameters..Am i Right??

Comment: Absolutely. Its up to the other function to pass the arguments when it uses the passed function.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method expects a function pointer as argument. It will then loop through the array and invoke this function. You could also have used an anonymous function:

```
n.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a- b;
});
```

Comment: Thanks..Can you describe something about a function pointer. Just for the above code                                                              I am not aware much about the pointers..can u explain so that i wld be clear about the above code.

Comment: @user460920, Array.sort is a function that expects another function as argument. So you are passing the name of the function as argument. This is the pointer to this function. If you wrote for example `Array.sort(sortNumber(5, 6))` then you are no longer passing a function as argument but you are passing the result of the execution of this function as argument which is not what the Array.sort method expects.

Comment: thanks..so can we say that the above function is a recursive function

Comment: @user460920, no, a recursive function is one that calls itself. This is not the case with Array.sort. It calls the function you are passing as argument.

Comment: Sorry.. I was telling abt the below function that is it a recursive..I am too confused..How does it works i am not clear...                                                           function sortNo(a,b)
 {
    return a - b;
 }

Comment: @user460920, there's nothing recursive in this function. It's a normal function taking 2 arguments and returning the difference between them.